# How to parse the following array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, parsing

```
set_data_search([
              {"total":1},
              {"id":"14288",
                "v":"HDB Clementi",
                "i":"107A Clementi Street 12. (S)121107",
                "t":"1",
                "pid":"3448",
                "aid":"7896",
                "lid":"14288",
                "lon":"103.770138",
                "lat":"1.322042",
                "ad":"0",
                "c":"99",
                "bld":"1",
                "hsp":1
            }]);
```

I need 107A Clementi Street 12 from the above...

Comment: `yourArray[1]['i']` should do i suppose..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is JSONP. You can access the data by implementing the named function:

```
function set_data_search(data) {
    console.log(data[1].i);
}
```